# Как эскпортировать все функции в DLL?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

Я скачал исходники библиотеки `"A"` и теперь хочу собрать из нее `.dll`. Однако, в библиотеке нигде не указаны `__declspec(dllexport)`, что приводит к тому, что в `dll` ничего не попадает (оно совсем пустое и никак не работает) и более того, не генерируется `.lib` файл. Я не могу вручную везде добавить `dllexport`, может есть способы указать компилятору, что экспортируется все, что он сможет найти?